# Usage of std::swap() inside move assignment should cause endless recursion (and causes), but it is an example from Stroustrup's book

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, move-semantics

I'm trying to get the deep knowledge about how should I write my copy and move constructors and assignment operators.

In Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language - 2013" I see the following example of move constructor and move assignment:

```
template<class T, class A>
vector_base<T,A>::vector_base(vector_base&& a)
   : alloc{a.alloc},
   elem{a.elem},
   space{a.space},
   last{a.space}
{
   a.elem = a.space = a.last = nullptr; // no longer owns any memory
}

template<class T, class A>
vector_base<T,A>::& vector_base<T,A>::operator=(vector_base&& a)
{
   swap(∗this,a);
   return *this;
}
```

(*Side note: there seems to be a typo in the book: `::&` should be just `&`, right?*)

I suspected it should cause endless recursion, since `std::swap()` calls move assignment operator:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T& lhs, T& rhs)
{
  auto temp(lhs);
  lhs = std::move(rhs);
  rhs = std::move(temp);
}
```

I've checked it, here's very simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestA {
   int x;

public:
   TestA(int x = 0) : x(x) {
      cout << "TestA value ctor " << x << "\n";
   }

   ~TestA() {
      cout << "TestA dtor " << x << "\n";
   }

   TestA(const TestA &a) : x(a.x) {
      cout << "TestA copy ctor " << x << "\n";
   }

   TestA(TestA &&a) : x(a.x) {
      cout << "TestA move ctor " << x << "\n";
   }

   TestA operator=(const TestA &a) {
      x = a.getX();
      cout << "TestA copy assignment " << x << " = " << a.getX() << "\n";
      return *this;
   }

   TestA &operator=(TestA &&a) {
      cout << "TestA move assignment " << x << " = " << a.getX() << "\n";
      swap(*this, a);
      return *this;
   }

   int getX() const {
      return this->x;
   }

};

int main(void) {
   TestA a{0};
   TestA b{1};
   {
      TestA c{2};
      a = move(c);
   }
}
```

Which produces the following output, so I was right about endless recursion:

```
TestA value ctor 0
TestA value ctor 1
TestA value ctor 2
TestA move assignment 0 = 2
TestA move ctor 0
TestA move assignment 0 = 2
TestA move ctor 0
TestA move assignment 0 = 2
TestA move ctor 0
...
...
```

Do I miss something? How can I use `swap()` inside move assignment?

Comment: `last{a.space}` in the move constructor of `vector_base` looks just wrong -- shouldn't it be `last{a.last}`

Comment: No, the `space` is a struct member, here's a definition of it: http://vpaste.net/TyskU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is that Stroustroup provides a free-function `swap(TestA&, TestA&)` in the same namespace as the class.

Also, he does not call it as `std::swap` (neither does your code), but uses an unqualified id and injection of `std::swap` into the namespace with `using ::std::swap;`.

Which means the generic version provided by the standard is not used.

At least that is how it should be. Seems that free-standing `swap()` is really missing. Ouch.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds true, but I've just tried to find that free-function `swap()` in my pdf book file, and I failed to find it. Is it so obvious so that it doesn't even worth mentioning? :)

Comment: Does the code in the book actually take the argument as `vector_base&&` in the assignment operator? The copy and swap idiom usually uses a value parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2, yes, of course I've just copy-pasted the code. It's on page 379, section 13.6.2.

Comment: It should be somewhere in the book. I cannot verify it though, haven't got it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's not copy and swap. It's just using swap to implement move assignment, which is perfectly valid (assuming a specialized swap, of course).

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I figured that. Thanks.

Comment: @Deduplicator, just fyi: it is not, at least I and my pdf viewer failed to find it. Thanks for your answer, again.

Comment: I'm looking for this same std::swap and it's not there, not even on the errata on Stroustrup's website. Odd.

Answer (score 6):

You're not missing anything, and the accepted answer is wrong. Stroustrup's book is simply bad. There is no free-standing `swap()` anywhere in chapter 13; it's strongly implied that this `swap()` is `std::swap()` (just like `copy()` is `std::copy()`, etc.). It's just a bug. Welcome to C++.