# C++ - Move assignment operator without custom swap function?

Tags: c++, swap

I'm reading Stroustrup's book (4th ed) and saw this example:

```
template<typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
struct vector_base {                    // memory structure for vector
    A alloc;        // allocator
    T* elem;        // start of allocation
    T* space;       // end of element sequence, start of space allocated for possible expansion
    T* last;        // end of allocated space

    vector_base(const A& a, typename A::size_type n, typename A::size_type m =0)
        : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n+m)}, space{elem+n}, last{elem+n+m} { }
    ~vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(elem,last-elem); }

    vector_base(const vector_base&) = delete;           // no copy operations
    vector_base& operator=(const vector_base&) = delete;

    vector_base(vector_base&&);                     // move operations
    vector_base& operator=(vector_base&&);
};

template<typename T, typename A>
vector_base<T,A>::vector_base(vector_base&& a)
    : alloc{a.alloc},
    elem{a.elem},
    space{a.space},
    last{a.last}    
{
    a.elem = a.space = a.last = nullptr;    // no longer owns any memory
}

template<typename T, typename A>
vector_base<T,A>& vector_base<T,A>::operator=(vector_base&& a)
{
    swap(*this,a);
    return *this;
}
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550), I understand that you can't just `std::swap(*this, other)` in an assignment operator because `std::swap` is often implemented in terms of the assignment operator itself. Therefore, you first need to provide your own custom `swap` function.

Is this a mistake, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you don't provide your own swap, you may get a "generic" less efficient swap.

Comment: @Eljay that's not what I understood. If the generic swap does `T tmp = a; a = std::move(b); b = std::move(tmp);`, then the move assignments of `a` and `b` would in turn call `swap` again, endlessly, right?

Comment: Then that would be a problem, too.  Like code that implements assignment in terms of assignment.

Comment: There are many things that can be implemented different ways in C++ so do a careful reading to ensure that you take parts that works together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a duplicate of [Usage of std::swap() inside move assignment should cause endless recursion (and causes), but it is an example from Stroustrup's book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908004/usage-of-stdswap-inside-move-assignment-should-cause-endless-recursion-and). Seems like Stroustrup does define a custom swap function; I seem to have missed it.

EDIT: I haven't found the swap function. Seems like it's a mistake on the book.

Comment: I didn't find custom `swap` in the book. But you definitely need it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find it either. I guess it might've been a mistake.